# Add swipe ability to hide an HTML menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have menu built using CSS, when the user touches, the menu slides out and when he touches the background it slides in again on mobile.

The problem is that i want to make the menu work like in mobile app menu, rather than touching the background to slide in, i want the user to able able swipe and hide the menu

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/ek4tkrc0/2/

Below is the css

```
nav ul li { line-height: 50px; }

#nav {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    width: 60%;
    max-width: 275px;
    background: rgb(255, 219, 58);
    box-shadow: -3px 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    overflow-y: auto;
    z-index: 99;
}

#nav:not(:target) {
    left: -100%;
    transition: left .5s;
}

#nav:target {
    left: 0;
    transition: left .25s;
}

#nav:target + #nav_modal { display: block; }

#nav_modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function initialHash() {
  'use strict';
  window.location.href = "#";
}

document.getElementById('nav_modal').addEventListener('click', initialHash, false);
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You could use a jQuery plugin like [this](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/examples/panels/panel-swipe-open.html)

Comment: There is also a nice tutorial about it. You can read about it [here](http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/05/mobile-menu/)

Comment: @SimrandeepSingh Thanks.. I did have a look but the only problem with that is when the slide menu appears, the whole content moves. I wanted the content to fixed and only the menu to slide in and out on swipe

Comment: Added a working example using a fork of your jsfiddle. You can just move the menu using the touch events, and check if you have to either close the menu or keep it opened when the touch even ends :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use touchstart, touchmove, touchend events on #nav. Here is an example

```
function initialHash() {
  'use strict';
  window.location.href = "#";
}

function handleTouch(e) {
    var x = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
  var total = this.clientWidth;
  var position = x - total;
  if ( position < 0 ) this.style.left = (x-total) + 'px'
  else if (position >= 0) this.style.left = 0 + 'px'
}
function handleTouchEnd(e) {
    var x = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
  var total = this.clientWidth;
  var position = x - total;
  this.style.left = "";
  if ( position <= -total*0.5 ) initialHash();
}
document.querySelector('#nav').addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouch, false)
document.querySelector('#nav').addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouch, false)
document.querySelector('#nav').addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, false)
document.getElementById('nav_modal').addEventListener('click', initialHash, false);
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/cnexans/Ln60t4h6/1/

Comment: Thanks.. Works great :)